# Unable to edit color of text in Adobe Photoshop CC 2020

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, text, education

I'm currently working through the official training workbook, the 2019 release, and am halted on Chapter 7. I'm trying to edit the text, and I'm able to do everything but edit the text color. I'm selected on the layer it's on too, however when my layers are selected they are highlighted red now. Photoshop is a jack in the box, and would rather not have to restart the Chapter. I'll be clicking buttons until things work for now, but I'd love to hear from some professionals.

Comment: Hi Zachary! I'm sorry to tell you that this is a bit too little to go on. First off, what version of Photoshop are you on? It would also help if you could include a screenshot of your situation so we can more easily telly you where to click. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to change text color in Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/703/unable-to-change-text-color-in-photoshop)

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see a screenshot of what exactly the issue is but check if you do not have the text layer locked. If it is you have to open the layer before you can edit the text.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Text tool.
Select Layer [in the right-hand layers panel].

[image]

Click the colour box in the top bar.

[image]

Pick a colour.

Alternatively, select the text box itself, then any or all letters within it.
If you select individual characters, then only the colour of those selected will change.

[image]

This methodology has changed slightly in recent versions. I don't do a lot of text, so I'm not sure when it changed, but this works for CC2020.
In older versions, any time you wanted to change colour it seemed the entire selected text would invert, so you couldn't see the actual colour until you'd finished. [Either I'd never figured it out properly in older versions, or this one is a significant improvement ;)